# How to create flask-sqlalchemy tables with models in blueprints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.9

I am developing an application with `flask` y `flask-sqlalchemy`, in Python 3.9.

First, I created a simple and small application (no Blueprints), with a single model for users.

`db.create_all()` worked without problems.

I expanded the application and decided to divide it into blueprints. The application and connection to the database **still** worked correctly: users can login.

So, I decided to create another model, but `db.create_all()` did not work. The new table was not created. And, after emptying the database, the first table of users was not created either.

I have seen several posts on the Internet, where the problem is that it is necessary to import the models, or where the app context is missing:

```
with app.app_context():
   db.create_all()
```

Even if the models are imported and executing in the context of the app, the tables are not created.

On the other hand, if I copy the class of the model and paste it in the file where I run `db.create_app()`, the tables are created. From what I understand that it is a problem of how the models are imported or how I define the blueprints. SQLAlchemy does not detect the models.

**[entrypoint.py] This works:**

```
import numpy as np
from app import create_app, db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'it_user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=True, nullable=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}:{}>'.format(self.id, self.username)


    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    ....

class Simulation(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'it_simulation'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    symbol = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=False)
    simulations = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    predictions = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Float), nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, symbol, date, simulations):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.date = date
        self.simulations = simulations

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Simulation {}:{}_{}_{}>'.format(self.id, self.symbol, self.date, self.simulations)

    ...

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    ...

app = create_app()
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

**[entrypoint.py] But this doesn't work:**

```
from app.probabilities.models import Simulation
from app.auth.models import User
from app import create_app, db

app = create_app()
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

**Here is my project structure:**

```
Project
|-- requirements.txt
|-- entrypoint.py
+-- app
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- ... (templates, static...)
    |-- auth
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- forms.py
    |   |-- models.py
    |   |-- routes.py
    |   +-- templates
    +-- probabilities
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- forms.py
        |-- models.py
        |-- routes.py
        +-- templates
```

**[app/__init__.py] App initialization:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from app.navbars import get_navbars
from decouple import config

login_manager = LoginManager()
db = SQLAlchemy()

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
nav = get_navbars()

def create_app():
    #### [CONFIG FLASK] ####
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = config('FLASK_SECRET')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(
        config('DB_USER'),
        config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        config('DB_HOST'),
        config('DB_PORT'),
        config('DB_DATABASE')
    )
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    #### [CONFIG LOGIN ] ####
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

    #### [CONFIG DATABASE] ####
    db.init_app(app)

    #### [CONFIG NAVIGATION BAR] ####
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    nav.init_app(app)

    #### [BLUEPRINTS] ####
    from .auth import auth_bp
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)
    from .probabilities import probabilities_bp
    app.register_blueprint(probabilities_bp)

    return app
```

Both blueprints are created in a similar way. As an example, here is "probabilities":

**[probabilities/__init__.py]**

```
from flask import Blueprint

probabilities_bp = Blueprint('probabilities', __name__, template_folder='templates')

from . import routes
```

**[probabilities/models.py]**

```
from app.__init__ import db
import numpy as np

class Simulation(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'it_simulation'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    symbol = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=False)
    simulations = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    predictions = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Float), nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, symbol, date, simulations):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.date = date
        self.simulations = simulations

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Simulation {}:{}_{}_{}>'.format(self.id, self.symbol, self.date, self.simulations)

    ...

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    ...
```

Is there a way to create tables without moving  each of the models every time I want to edit the tables? `flask-migrate` does not detect the models either and, therefore, do not find changes to update.

I guess there is, and as I see on the Internet works. But I'm not able to see the error at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really get to understand the reason, but it seems to be an import problem with the `db` object.

In `entrypoint.py`, the `db` object is imported as:

```
from app import create_app, db
```

But both `models.py` files import it like this:

```
from app.__init__ import db
```

It is solved by importing the `db` object in the same way in all the files (using `from app import db` or `from app.__init__ import db`). But always in the same way.

Another alternative is, in the `entrypoint.py` file, import `db` from one of the `models.py` files.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that model classes I created in `models.py` had not been  imported into the submodules where they were they needed to be. It is a bit confusing how these models get passed around by `flask`. Your models shouldn't be imported into the `__init__.py` because you end up with a circular import issue, it become part of the app object which is then passed along to your `db.init_app(app)` call in `__init__.py`. SQLAlchemy will then be able to pick up on the models that have been passed within the app argument.

```py
...
from project.models import User

home_bp = Blueprint(
    'home_bp', __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static') 

@home_bp.route('/', endpoint='home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = UserForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User()
        user.name = form.name.data
        user.email = form.email.data
        user.password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method="pbkdf2:sha256", salt_length=8)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("index.html")
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
```